# documentation on imageJ's FFT bandpass filter function

Tags: fft, documentation, imagej, bandpass-filter

Does anyone here have any idea where I can find documentation on imageJ's FFT bandpass filter function?

Or even better: a precise explanation of which operations are necessary on the Powerspectrum in order to "filter large structures down to size x and small ones down to size y".

So far I have not been able to find anything here:

1. https://imagej.net/ij/docs/menus/process.html#smooth

2. Burger and Burges "Digital image processing - an algorithmic introduction with Java"

Comment: ImageJ is open source. You can look at the source code and see how it works.

Comment: You've already received quite some help in response to the same question here: <https://www.reddit.com/r/ImageJ/comments/18ypenf/fftbandpassfilter/> As long as you don't make clear what you are really after, it is impossible to give more advice. If you still like to get an introduction to Fourier-theory, I'm sorry to tell you that here is not the right place to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

The following page contains some information about the fft bandpass filter function in ImageJ and some usage examples: https://imagej.net/ij/plugins/fft-filter.html.

Some more information and images can be found here as well: https://imagej.net/ij/docs/examples/FFT/

Answer (score 0):

> […] which operations are necessary on the Powerspectrum in order to
> 'filter large structures down to size x and small ones down to size y'.

Literally **no operations** are necessary on the Fourier power-spectrum, because the Fourier power-spectrum is not involved in Fourier-filtering.